# Why does *(a+b) work in C instead of a[b]?

Tags: c, arrays

I've read in the C99 standard that that is how arrays are expanded, but I can't wrap my head around why that would work. If I have

```
a[5]
```

and a is an integer, then wouldn't that be accessing the second element and not the fifth (assuming integers are four bytes in size)? Shouldn't it expand to

```
*(a+5*sizeof(a))
```

since each byte gets its own address?

Comment: "*(a+5*sizeof(a))" is correct, I'm not sure what your confusion is.

Comment: When you use the "+" operator on a pointer, it anyway adds the `sizeof(type)` bytes, where `type` is the type of your array. For example, if `int` is 8 bytes, it will add 8 to your pointer

Comment: I just tested that and it does not work.

Comment: @user1128279, just add 5, do NOT add `5*sizeof(whatever)`

Comment: Unless you want to progress your pointer in bytes, then you need to first cast it to a char pointer, which is a type that is 1 byte on any architecture

Comment: @SomethingSomething, yes, but only if you *define* the size of byte to be that of char. sizeof returns in terms of chars, not in terms of 8 bits, which is the most common use of the word byte. At least in C++, a char does not need to be 8 bits.

Comment: 'a' should not be a integer... 'a' should be a pointer to an integer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is based on the size of the pointed-to type; if you have a pointer `p` to a type `T`, then `p+1` gives you the address of the next instance of that type.  So, given something like the following:

```
char *pc   = 0x1000;
int  *ic   = 0x1000;
double *dc = 0x1000;
```

`pc + 1` gives the address of the next `char` object (which will be at `0x1001`), `ic + 1` gives the address of the next `int` object (which will be at `0x1004` for a four-byte `int`), and `dc + 1` gives the address of the next `double` object (which will be at `0x1008` for an 8-byte `double`).

This is why `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)` - you're accessing the `i`'th *element* of the array, not the `i`'th *byte* of the array.

Comment: But why would C add the size of the type instead of a one?

Comment: I would add in a comment that if for some reason he wants to work with bytes, he can cast his pointer to `char*` and then cast it back to the original pointer type

Comment: @user1128279: Because it's useful.  Because it makes array indexing work the same whether if I'm working with an array of `char` or an array of `struct humongous`.  `a[i]` gives me the exact same behavior as `b[i]` (give me the `i`th element of each array), regardess of the types of `a` and `b`

Comment: @user1128279, who decided that `byte` is the correct unit? Why won't it add just `one bit`? This is how it works..

Comment: @John Bode Yes, but why not just have array subscripting handle that, and have all pointers act the same except for when they're dereferenced (as I had previously thought it worked)?

Comment: @user1128279: Because that's less convenient in 99.99% of all use cases. Why should it do that?

Comment: @user1128279: Array subscripting *is* pointer arithmetic under the hood - `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)`.  DMR wanted C's array semantics to match B's (an earlier, "typeless" language that Ken Thompson derived from BCPL).  And in that language, pointer arithmetic and array subscripting were the same operation.  It's just that in B everything was the same size (no distinct types for characters, integers, floats, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

This is pointer arithmetic. `A[I]` is exactly `*(A+I)`. Now, what `A+I` means? It is the address of `I`-th element of `A`. If `A` is an **array** of `int`s then `A+5` is the address of the 6-th element of the array `A`.
When you measure in **bytes**, the value of the address is the value of the address of `A` plus `5*sizeof(int)` in **bytes**.

Answer (score 0):

Each element in an array of ints, holds a sizeof(int) space to store the number.
So technically your array is a sizeof(int)*size.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a long time since I actually coded in C so forgive me if I make a mistake in the syntax or function calls.

An array is simply like a linear table of elements (strings, ints, floats, chars, structs, etc), a[5] is telling the compiler to get to the 6th element in that "table" regardless of what type it is. The compiler knows how many memory locations to jump based on the type the array variable was declared as.

Now, when you are pointing to memory, you retrieving the content by using a pointer to the location in memory where you want to start, in the case of an array of integers, you need to tell it how many memory locations each integer is in order to jump and get the data from the represented array element.

With this in mind, lets supposed that "a" represents an array in memory that has been allocated with integers as elements, in this case, if you do:

```
int *a = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));

/* initialize a with values */

/* .... some time later retrieve the 6th element: a[5] */
int x = *(a + 5);
```

The program will first jump over 5 "a" elements, which are as we know integers, by doing:

```
sixth_element_address = a+5*sizeof(a)
```

then retrieves the contents and assigns it to an integer variable:

```
x = *(sixth_element_address)
```

So using array notation is the same as doing it with pointer notation as you see.

Now, the only reason I would use pointer notation is when I do not have declared an array variable itself.